# Spring Roo + Webflow: Could not serialize flow execution.

Tags: spring-roo

this is my error when I try to open the flow :

> Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable

But all my models are @RooJavaBean. Is possibile these are not serializable?

Thanks!

p.s. Full error message

> message: "org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

@RooSerializable